# Can i save photos to the camera roll without user explicit consent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i'm developing an iPhone application that let users to take photos. Those photos are saved inside the application, but i would like also to save them to the camera roll. 
The problem is that my application does not have a UI control that let the user specify if he wants the photo to be saved also in the camera roll.
I searched the Apple guidelines and documentation but could not find any hint regarding this issue.
So in your experience is ok to save photos taken by the user also in the camera roll without asking his permission?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to write to camera roll without permission..but it is better to show a successful save alert once you save photo.. user won't be happy if you are saving unnecessary/involuntary photo without some feedback to user

```
void UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (
   UIImage  *image,
   id       completionTarget,
   SEL      completionSelector,
   void     *contextInfo
);
```

above is the method to save the image .. it can be find in apple docs here [Save to camera roll](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: FYI, this is not true in iOS 6 and above.  Permissions are still required using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is taking the photo himself by tapping a button or whatever, saving to the camera roll is the best you could do, IMO, and I don't think you need to show an alert or whichever kind of notice.

The only thing, make sure the user knows where he should go to retrieve his pictures...

Comment: The user can see the saved photos inside the application (i save the original version and a thumbnail version)